# Can i clear overrides on master pages in Indesign without loosing the content?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a long Indesign CC document with pages based on masterpages with different layouts using empty frames. I am overriding the masterpages when I am putting images into the frames. And along the way I have moved the frames around so the dont match the masterpages in terms of position of the frames. Now i want to clear the overrides in terms of positioning of the frames so the match the master pages I have altered. But I don´t want to loose the images and have to put them back into the frames.(this is what happens now when I clear overrides) Because it is a lot of images and i want to save myself some work.

Is there by any chance any way to do this?